# Set a variable inside case statement in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following scenario

```
SELECT
...
...
(
   @var1 = MAX(IF(table1.name='Mod', table1.value, NULL))
   @var2 = MAX(IF(table1.name='Man', table1.value, NULL))
     CASE
        WHEN @var1 IS NOT NULL && @var2 IS NOT NULL THEN @var1+"/"+@var2
        WHEN @var1 IS NULL && @var2 IS NOT NULL THEN @var2
        WHEN @var1 IS NOT NULL && @var2 IS NULL THEN @var1
        ELSE NULL
END) AS "col44",
```

This is throwing me an exception in the mysql console.

Can't we do a variable assignment in the general mysql select query?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near` '@var2= MAX(IF(table1.name='Man', table1.value, NULL))`

Comment: What about the commas at the end of each variable expression? is that a typo? ( I can't be sure without seeing the whole `SELECT`)

Comment: The whole select is too large to post. It is working fine when I remove this variable assignment and case statement. 
It fails even when I add comma after each variable expression

Comment: May you can try with initializing `@var1` and `@var2` outside the select. This may solve your problem.

Comment: It's going to fail without commas because `... MAX(x) CASE ...` does not make any sense; and it will fail with commas because `SELECT (x, y, z) ` is not allowed

Comment: Not sure what the title of this question should be. I was looking for an example of setting a variable INSIDE `CASE` statement, but here the variables are set BEFORE the `CASE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

```
SELECT ...
   , @var1 = MAX(IF(table1.name='Mod', table1.value, NULL))
   , @var2 = MAX(IF(table1.name='Man', table1.value, NULL))
   , CASE
        WHEN @var1 IS NOT NULL && @var2 IS NOT NULL THEN @var1+"/"+@var2
        WHEN @var1 IS NULL && @var2 IS NOT NULL THEN @var2
        WHEN @var1 IS NOT NULL && @var2 IS NULL THEN @var1
        ELSE NULL
     END AS "col44"
```

Note the addition of commas, and removal of parenthesis.

---

Alternatively, you could just use a subquery. (In my experience, variables in queries *can* become unpredictable when used in conjunction with aggregation; this avoids the variables altogether).

```
   SELECT ...
         , CASE
            WHEN modMax IS NOT NULL && manMax IS NOT NULL THEN modMax+"/"+manMax
            WHEN modMax IS NULL && manMax IS NOT NULL THEN manMax
            WHEN modMax IS NOT NULL && manMax IS NULL THEN modMax
            ELSE NULL
         END AS "col44"
    FROM (
        SELECT ...
           , MAX(IF(table1.name='Mod', table1.value, NULL)) AS modMax
           , MAX(IF(table1.name='Man', table1.value, NULL)) AS manMax
        ...
      ) AS subQ
```

Additional note: Watch out for `modMax+"/"+manMax`; it may end up giving you an integer calculated from modMax+0+manMax, instead of a string.

Comment: Thanks.
The first method is working, however it is appending @ var1, @ var2 as columns to the result which l don't want

Comment: Just updated the second method for a way to avoid having those columns in the result; the only way to change the first query to omit them is to basically make it so much like the second one that you might as well use the second one.